# Yes/No Format for query column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query, simplified for this question:

```
SELECT convert(bit, Substring(Max(convert(CHAR(8), tt.transaction_dt, 112) + convert(CHAR(1), tt.trans_live)), 9, 1)) AS is_live
FROM transaction_t tt
```

The query is designed to determine if a particular merchant has a "live" status depending on the "trans_live" value of the merchant's LATEST transaction record.

This returns a "1" or "0". However, I need a "yes/no" formatted column value.

NOTE: The section of the query as follows:

```
Max(convert(CHAR(8), tt.transaction_dt, 112) + convert(CHAR(1), trans_live))
```

returns a result in the following format:

```
202006271
```

Following is the relevant table structure:

**transaction_t**

```
id     transaction_dt     trans_live     merchant_id
-----------------------------------------------------
1      2020-04-02         0              4
2      2020-04-02         1              4
3      2020-04-03         1              4
4      2020-04-04         0              4
4      2020-06-27         1              4
```

Comment: Please use `case statement` like below, `SELECT CASE convert(bit, Substring(Max(convert(CHAR(8), tt.transaction_dt, 112) + convert(CHAR(1), tt.trans_live)), 9, 1)) WHEN 0 THEN 'no' WHEN 1 THEN 'yes' END AS is_live FROM transaction_t tt`

Comment: Seems like a job for your presentation layer.

Comment: *"What was wrong with my question by the way, to get downvoted? Add your solution as an answer and I'll mark it correct*" Providing an answer, or even a comment, along with a downvote isn't required. Votes, on questions, are meant to show that the voter felt that the question was not helpful or lacked research. I can only guess, but I assume that the downvoters felt the latter (as searching how to convert a `bit` to `'Yes'`/`'No'` will bring you the solution in many languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **case statement** like below,

```sql
SELECT CASE (convert(bit, Substring(Max(convert(CHAR(8), tt.transaction_dt, 112) + convert(CHAR(1), tt.trans_live)), 9, 1))) 
   WHEN '0' THEN 'no' 
   WHEN '1' THEN 'yes' 
END AS is_live 
FROM transaction_t tt
```

Syntax may be wrong but this would help

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `iif` like below:

```
SELECT iif(convert(bit, Substring(Max(convert(CHAR(8), tt.transaction_dt, 112) + convert(CHAR(1), tt.trans_live)), 9, 1)) = 1, 'Yes', 'No')  AS is_live
FROM transaction_t tt
```

db<>fillde [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0432dae15b7c55ba07c9b62c10448cc2).

Comment: Nice solution too.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the reason for the downvote is that you are doing something very "weird" here. But your question is fairly clear.

I understand the issue you are trying to solve: you want to get the trans_live value for the row with the most recent transaction date. But you can't see how to do that using max, because something like `trans_live, max(transaction_dt) group by trans_live` doesn't do what you want, and neither does `max(transaction_dt), max(trans_live)`.

So you have come up with a rather "clever" solution: convert both to character values, concatenate them, sort them, and then split out the least siginificant "figure" from the concatenated value.

But the thing is, there are ways to do this sort of thing that are more natural in the language. Your way is a clever workaround, but it's cryptic.It's also a bit dangerous unless your trasaction_dt column is a date (and not a datetime), otherwise you are truncating the time part, in which case two transactions on the same date with different times will have the same truncated value, and then the one with trans_live = 1 will always be sorted higher than the one with trans_live = 0

A much simpler solution would be something like this:

```
create table transaction_t(merchant_id int, transaction_dt datetime, trans_live bit)
go

;with merchants as 
(
   select   distinct 
            merchant_id 
   from     transaction_t
)
select      m.merchant_id,
            is_live = t.trans_live
from        merchants m
cross apply (
               select   top 1 trans_live
               from     transaction_t
               where    merchant_id = m.merchant_id
               order by transaction_dt desc
            ) t

-- OR

select   distinct
         merchant_id, 
         is_live = first_value(trans_live) over
                   (
                      partition by merchant_id
                      order by transaction_dt desc
                   )
from     transaction_t

-- OR

select   merchant_id,
         is_live
from     (
            select   merchant_id,
                     is_live = trans_live,
                     rn = row_number() over 
                     (
                        partition by merchant_id 
                        order by transaction_dt desc
                     )
            from    transaction_t
         ) t 
where    t.rn = 1
```

Edit: And if you are only looking for the result for a single merchant...

```
declare @merchant_id int = 1;

select      top 1 
            is_live = trans_live
from        transaction_t
where       merchant_id = @merchant_id
order by    transaction_dt desc
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't create this query. I just have to deal with it.

Comment: It's always a good time to clean up technical debt! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, you have to use case statement to get your result. You can use required columns in the select statement. Hope this is your expectation, if not let me know

```
select 
convert(bit, Substring(Max(convert(CHAR(8), tt.transaction_dt, 112) + convert(CHAR(1), 
tt.trans_live)), 9, 1)) AS is_live,
case when trans_live = 1 then 'Yes' 
   when trans_live = 0 then 'No' end as  trans_live
from transaction_t tt
```

Answer (score 0):

> The query is designed to determine if a particular merchant has a "live" status depending on the "trans_live" value of the merchant's LATEST transaction record.

I would expect a query like this:

```
select merchant_id, 
       (case when max(tt.transaction_dt) = max(case when tt.trans_live = 1 then tt.transaction_dt)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as is_live
from transaction_t tt
group by merchant_id;
```

I'm a bit baffled by what your query has to do with your question.